# httpclient conflict with classes now provided by Android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, apache-httpclient-4.x

In Android Studio 3.4.1

```
app/build.gradle:


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But I get error in this line;

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
```

error:

```
httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. more... (Ctrl+F1)
```

Comment: What happends when you remove this line from the build.gradle? Which classes of this library are you using?

Comment: @oemel09 Then I get compile error: import org.apache.http.HttpHost;  - can't resolve symbol HttpHost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this changelog for the [Android API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client).
You should replace the Apache HTTP functions by [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or use this snipped in your `build.gradle` to continue using the now deprecated Apache libraries.

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```